# Set object property from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the example:

```
var side = 'left';

$('div').css({
  position: 'relative',
  side: 50
});
```

I put variable `side` instead real property name. I was expecting that this will work, but... :)

So, how to set property name from varaibles value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way is to declare previously your object as a variable...

```
var options = {
  position: 'relative'
};
options[side] = 50;
$('div').css(options);
```

Comment: this might not work because `50` is not a valid css property, the unit is missing (for instance px)

Comment: @Alex jQuery will use it as pixels by default

Comment: i made different experiences... since what version?